# Find the eigenvalues of a polynomial transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Say $$F_2[X]:=\{p(x)=ax^2+bx+c:a,b,c \in F\}$$
>   And the linear operator T:$F_2[X] \to F_2[X]$
>   defined as:
>
> $$T(ax^2+bx+c)=(2a+6b+5c)-(8a+b)x+(c-2a)x^2$$
>
> How can I find the eigenvalues and the characteristic vectors of T?

Sorry that I have not done literally a thing, I don't know how to find eigenvalues of a polynomial transformation

Comment: Hint : 
The definition of this transformation makes it easy to write its matrix representation in the canonical base $(p_1,p_2,p_3)=\left(1,X,X^2\right)$ of $F_2[X]$. Then recall that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear transformation are the same as those of its representative matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues and polynomial spaces are a linear algebra topic. I don't know if you are familiar with it, but linear algebra is algebra, so the whole points is it genericity : results and method are applicable to whole cathegory of objects. So the fact that it's a specific polynomial transformation doesn't change anything, you can just proceed like with any kind of transformation.

Here, $\dim\left(F_2[X]\right)=3$ : we work with a finite dimensional space.

This is how I would proceed :

1. Find the matrix $M(T)\in M_{3,3}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ associated with the transformation, in the canonical basis $(p_1,p_2,p_3)=\left(1,X,X^2\right)$ of $F_2[X]$. If you are not familiar with it, $M(T)$ is constructed as follows : the $i^{th}$ colomn represents the coordinates of $T(p_i)$ in the basis $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$. Since we are in finite dimension, any vector is just a linear combination of this basis, so this matrix encodes all the information of $T$. Here, $T(1)=5+X^2, T(X)=6-X, T(X^2)=2-8X-2X^2$, so $$M(T)=\begin{pmatrix} 
   5 & 6 & 2 \\
   0 & -1 & -8 \\
   1 & 0 & -2 
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   It's actually just another representation of the definition of $T$ you stated, but the point is that it's much more readable.
2. Here, $M(T)$ displays no trivial eigenvalues, so we probably have to find its characteristic polynomial. $$\chi_M(\lambda)=-\det\left(M(T)-\lambda I_3\right)$$ and the eigenvalues of $M$ (and of $T$) are the roots of this polynomial.

Can you take it on from here ?

Comment: Thank you very much! You made it much clearer!

Comment: You're welcome !